# What would the punctuation be after "But I had to ask myself"

Tags: punctuation, word-usage

I want to write this

> But I had to ask myself what do I want to learn more of and am I ready to devote myself?

Please help me with this whole sentence punctuation and wording!

Answer (score 0):

See the section titled "Indirect Questions Mixed with Direct Questions".
http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/punctuating-questions?page=1

According to that reference, you would put a comma after (the first) "myself" and leave the rest alone as correct.